# Is there a function to combine multiple primary keys info into table?

Tags: r, concatenation, primary-key

I have two separate tables that have different primary keys and I need to join them together. One table provides the outcome and another table provides the ID of the people involved. Because there are multiple outcomes, and there are multiple people who could have similar outcomes, my table joins are not syncing up properly. I may be missing a step here and not thinking things logically, but any advice is greatly appreciated.

I originally tried joining the table by using this function I found:

```
rbind.all.columns <- function(x, y) {

    x.diff <- setdiff(colnames(x), colnames(y))
    y.diff <- setdiff(colnames(y), colnames(x))

    x[, c(as.character(y.diff))] <- NA

    y[, c(as.character(x.diff))] <- NA

    return(rbind(x, y))
}
```

However, all it does it provides me with the the outcome and the list of IDs.

Table 1:

```
EVENT   ID
145754  1738
145754  1756
145639  1738
145639  1756

df1 <- structure(list(EVENT = c(145754L, 145754L, 145639L, 145639L), ID = c(1738L, 1756L, 1738L, 1756L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Table 2:

```
ENTRY   EVENT   RESULT
DEL     145754  Was given xxx med
INS     145754  
DEL     145639  Reported stomachache
INS     145639  

df2 <- structure(list(ENTRY = c("DEL", "INS", "DEL", "INS"), EVENT = c(145754L, 145754L, 145639L, 145639L), RESULT = c("Was given xxx med", "", "Reported stomachache", "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

DESIRED TABLE:

```
ID          EVENT   RESULT
1738, 1756  145754  Was given xxx med
1738, 1756  145639  Reported stomachache
```

Comment: "Because there are multiple..." This describes the input & output of code giving the *wrong* result. Describe desired output as a function of input. For a given event what function of its matching table 2 rows do you want? PS When giving relation(ship)s/associations or tables say exactly what a row says about the business situation in terms of its column values when it is in the table. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When describing a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution.  [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

What we need to do is use `paste` to concatenate IDs for the same EVENT into a comma separated list:

```
library(tidyverse)
df1_concat <- df1 %>%
    group_by(EVENT) %>%
    summarise(IDs = paste(ID, collapse = ', '))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
   EVENT IDs       
   <int> <chr>     
1 145639 1738, 1756
2 145754 1738, 1756
```

Then we can just do a `*_join` on the EVENT column:

```
left_join(df2, df1_concat, by = 'EVENT')

  ENTRY  EVENT               RESULT        IDs
1   DEL 145754    Was given xxx med 1738, 1756
2   INS 145754                      1738, 1756
3   DEL 145639 Reported stomachache 1738, 1756
4   INS 145639                      1738, 1756
```

It's not clear to me why the rows where `ENTRY == 'INS'` are being removed, but depending on the logic here, there are many ways to filter them out. I show 2 below:

```
# Remove rows where ENTRY == 'DEL'

left_join(df1_concat, df2, by = 'EVENT') %>%
    filter(ENTRY == 'DEL')

# A tibble: 2 x 4
   EVENT IDs        ENTRY RESULT              
   <int> <chr>      <fct> <fct>               
1 145639 1738, 1756 DEL   Reported stomachache
2 145754 1738, 1756 DEL   Was given xxx med   


# Remove rows with no value for RESULT

left_join(df1_concat, df2, by = 'EVENT') %>%
    filter(RESULT != '')

# A tibble: 2 x 4
   EVENT IDs        ENTRY RESULT              
   <int> <chr>      <fct> <fct>               
1 145639 1738, 1756 DEL   Reported stomachache
2 145754 1738, 1756 DEL   Was given xxx med
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your thoroughness and explanation enabled me to see what I did wrong, and how to move forward. And the example code works. It provided me with the table I needed for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

In base R we actually could do this with a one-liner with `aggregate`, `merge`, and `toString` (for the IDs).

```
d <- aggregate(ID ~ EVENT + RESULT, merge(df1, df2[which(df2$RESULT != ""), ]), toString)
d
#    EVENT               RESULT         ID
# 1 145639 Reported stomachache 1738, 1756
# 2 145754    Was given xxx med 1738, 1756
```